# при сохранении json в файле появляются лишние символы. python

Tags: python, json, bs4

имеется примерная такая html страница, внутри которой есть json. При сохрании в файл, появляется символ переноса строки \n и экранируются элементы.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

html_block = str('''<div class="microformat"><script type="application/ld+json">[{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MusicEvent","name":"Artist"}]</script></div>''')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_block, "html.parser")
js = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").text
get_json = (json.dumps(json.loads(js), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
print(get_json)

with open("data.json", mode="w") as json_file:
    json.dump(get_json , json_file)
```

При выводе на экран все красиво:

```
[
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "MusicEvent",
        "name": "Artist"
    }
]
```

Но файл выглядит вот:

```
"[\n    {\n        \"@context\": \"http://schema.org\",\n        \"@type\": \"MusicEvent\",\n        \"name\": \"Artist\"\n    }\n]"
```

Если убрать indent=4, то и \n пропадает. Как можно сохранить файл, что бы он внутри выглядел, так же красиво, как при выводе на экран?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы два раза делаете преобразование.

В `get_json` у вас уже строка со сформированным json-ом. Второй раз делать `json.dump` не нужно. Просто пишите в файл:

```
with open("data.json", mode="w")
    json_file.write(get_json)
```

Или не делайте сохранения в строку, а сразу пишите в файл:

```
js = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").text
with open("data.json", mode="w") as json_file:
    json.dump(json.loads(js), json_file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: А если еще требуется дозаписывать данные в json файл? пробую через append, либо дозаписывает в файл необходимые данные, но без форматирования, либо в файле остается только последнее значение

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с подробностями. Я не понимаю из вопроса, что именно вы делаете (какой код) и что получается, и в комментариях такой вопрос задавать неудобно, да и не для этого они предназначены.

Comment: задал новый вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339465/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-json-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-python